# JavaScript .call understanding

Tags: javascript

That is a code that is used as an addition to a URL for a XMLHttpRequest.What comes out in the url is:

http://something/something.aspx?QueryString_from_below

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName("radio"), 0)
    .find(function (el, pos, arr) {
        if (el.checked == true) {
            return el
        }
    }).id.replace("option", "") + "=" + document.getElementById("searchField").value;
```

So it puts the radios in an array,searches for the checked box,assembles the queryString but I cant figure out the part:  `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName("radio"), 0)`.Why call an argument 0 on an array?The output of that and this:
`document.getElementsByName("radio")`
is identical.

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName("radio"), 0)` is copying the _array-like_ **collection** returned by `getElementsByName` and next operations are operating on the array returned by `slice`.

Comment: I guess it copies it so it can work with find() which seems to be JQuery function. Because both(`Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName("radio"), 0)` and `document.getElementsByName("radio")`) give me the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument represents the **end** position for slicing.
So in your case, it'd extract only one element provided that `document.getElementsByName("radio")` has an index of `0`.
Reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)